# Sorting Strings that contain integers with comparator

Tags: java, regex, sorting, comparator

I have a comparator that sorts an array of strings that contain letters and numbers, but can't seem to identify the regular expression that sorts them in the manner I am looking for.

I have used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java) as a reference for my comparator.

```
array={string-a01,string-a20,string-a100,string-b01,string-b20,string-b100,string-c01,string-c20,string-c100 etc.}

Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<String>(){       
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
    }

    int extractInt(String s) {
        String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
        return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
    }
});
        
for (String element : array) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Before Introducing the comparator the output was:
`string-a01, string-a100, string-a20, string-b01, string-b100, string-b20, string-c01, string-c20, string-c100`

The output that this code produces is: 
`string-a01, string-b01, string-c01 string-a20, string-b20, string-c20 string-a100, string-b100, string-c100`

The output I would like it to produce is:
`string-a01, string-a20, string-a100, string-b01, string-b20, string-b100, string-c01, string-c20, string-c100`

**EDIT:** Edited for clarification. Array has been changed and output before the comparator was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `string` part is actually something else than just `"string"`. You can extract the letter part of the ending, and the digit part, and compare those using a composite Comparator:

```
String[] array = { "string-a20", "string-a01", "string-b01",
    "string-b20", "string-c01", "string-c20",
    "string-a100", "string-b100", "string-c100" };

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?-([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)$");

List<String> result = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(p::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Matcher m) -> m.group(1)) // Compare the letter part
        .thenComparingInt(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)))) // Compare the number part
    .map(m -> m.group(0)) // Map back to String
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[string-a01, string-a20, string-a100, string-b01, string-b20, string-b100, string-c01, string-c20, string-c100]
```

---

Legacy version (With the downside of having to recreate `Matcher`s):

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?-([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)$");

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Matcher m1 = p.matcher(o1);
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher(o2);

        if(!(m1.find() && m2.find()))
            return 0; // Or throw a format exception

        int comparison = m1.group(1).compareTo(m2.group(1));
        return comparison != 0
            ? comparison 
            : Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)), Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)));
    }

});
```

Comment: I have made another update because the inital question didnt ask for everything i was looking for. The issue is that it orders like this: b01, b100, b11, c01, c100, c11... the array is generated dynamically and didnt realize the problem wouldnt occur with the original array posted

Comment: @Jon, Yeah I was looking into that, but it's a little more complicated.

Comment: @Jon [PLUS ONE] This must be the answer because of using lambdas perfectly to elaborate the answer in the most easiest way

Comment: @JornVernee Unfortunately, the version of java I'm running doesn't support lambdas and on this project upgrading isn't an option

Comment: @Jon That's unfortunate, I added a legacy version too.

Comment: @JornVernee Works like a charm! For anyone with the same issue dont forget the `private final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?-([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)$");` Thanks!!

Comment: @jon, OK it's added now

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the alphabetical characters in your `extractInt` method, so you won't be able to use them in the comparison.

You should just sort them with **no** `Comparator`, which will sort them using the default, lexicographical sorting algorithm (`java.lang.String` implements `Comparable<String>`).

**Example**

```
// test array
String[] s = {"string-a01","string-a01","string-b01","string-b02","string-c02","string-c02"};

// sorting with null Comparator, will sort if the type implements Comparable - 
// which String does
Arrays.sort(s);

// printing in human-readable form
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(s)
);
```

**Output**

```
[string-a01, string-a01, string-b01, string-b02, string-c02, string-c02]
```

**Notes**

- If you want to remove duplicates (which might be your intent from the question - not clear), add the array elements to a `TreeSet` instead:

  ```
  Set<String> deduplicated = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(s));
  ```
- If your sorting algorithm must act so that `2` comes before `12`, then you need to extract the integer value *without removing it* from the elements, and compare it only when the rest of the `String`s are equal.

Comment: Why don't you use lambda, easier

Comment: @GingerHead how is using the Java 8 stream API any "easier" than `Arrays.sort`, given this context?

Comment: For example `Arrays.sort(s, (a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());`

Comment: @GingerHead that will only achieve the desired result because the `String`s in the example are of the same length. Length of the `String` is nowhere a sorting criterium in OP's question, implied or not.

Comment: I just gave you a hint so that you would continue hereafter

Comment: @GingerHead `Arrays.sort(s)` is clearly simpler than `Arrays.sort(s, something)`.

Comment: @GingerHead thanks, I know how to use lambdas (at least for simple cases like this one). I'm just hinting that there's no good reason to use lambdas here, since OP's case doesn't seem to require anything but default sorting logic for `String`s.

Comment: @AndyTurner oops - too much distraction / not enough coffee.

Comment: @AndyTurner Regarding the complexity of its strings in the array better to use a rule than nothing to be on the safe side

Comment: @GingerHead nope. It's sufficient to rely upon well-documented behaviour.

Comment: @AndyTurner What if the elements changed in the future, usability is one of the major pillars of robust code architecture

Comment: @GingerHead I don't know what you mean. There is nothing unusable about `Arrays.sort`. There is nothing more robust about using a lambda function.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am addressing the changeability of the requirements

Comment: @Mena I have made another update because the inital question didnt ask for everything i was looking for. The issue is that it orders like this: b01, b100, b11, c01, c100, c11... the array is generated dynamically and didnt realize the problem wouldnt occur with the original array posted

Comment: @Jon see note 2 in my answer, or Andy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to order the strings on the "leading strings", i.e. everything up to the digits; if the leading strings are equal, then compare on the subsequent digits.

To split the string into its "string" and "integer" parts, you can first the "first trailing digit", i.e. the position of the first character in the string where there are no non-digits between it and the end of the string:

```
int firstTrailingDigit(String s) {
  int i = s.length();
  while (i > 0 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i - 1))) {
    --i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

You can then use this in your comparator:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
  int ftdA = firstTrailingDigit(a);
  int ftdB = firstTrailingDigit(b);

  // Get the leading strings, and compare.
  String sA = a.substring(0, ftdA);
  String sB = b.substring(0, ftdB);
  int compareStrings = sA.compareTo(sB);
  if (compareStrings != 0) {
    // If they're not equal, return the result of the comparison.
    return compareStrings;
  }

  // Get the trailing numbers from the strings, and compare.
  int iA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(ftdA));
  int iB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(ftdB));
  return Integer.compare(iA, iB);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/qn69m3)

Input:

```
String[] array = {"string-a01","string-a20","string-a100","string-b01","string-b20","string-b100","string-c01","string-c20","string-c100"};
```

Output:

```
[string-a01, string-a20, string-a100, string-b01, string-b20, string-b100, string-c01, string-c20, string-c100]
```