# NPE while attempting to call replaceAll() on ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

Okay, I understand what an NPE is, and why they are caused (most of the time), but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have an ArrayList of Strings, which is definitely not empty, because I have been displaying each element in a ListView previously.

I am using a custom Comparator:

```
public static class NumericalPodcastSort implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
        }

        int extractInt(String s) {
            String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", ""); << This is where the NPE is occurring.
            // return 0 if no digits found
            return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
        }
    }
```

to sort the integer part of each String in descending order (1, 2, 3, etc.), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java)

This is where I do the formatting and sorting of the ArrayList, before returning it and using it elsewhere.

```
public ArrayList<String> formatMindhiveTitles(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

    ArrayList<String> formattedTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

        String title = arrayList.get(i);

        formattedTitles.add(StringUtils.substringBetween(title, "mindhive podcast/", ".mp3"));
    }

    if (!formattedTitles.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.sort(formattedTitles, new FragmentUtilities.NumericalPodcastSort());
        return formattedTitles;
    }

    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have shuffled the `Collections.sort()` call around to several different places, but I continually receive

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I apologise if this is a simple fix, but for the life of me, I cannot work out why this is happening. It's not an issue of me using `ArrayList<String>` instead of `List<String>` is it? I shouldn't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In `extractInt()` before replacing, check the value of `s`. It is probably null

Comment: I know it's null, that's why I put the comment there. But `s` is assigned in the `compare()` method which should be sorting the Strings in the ArrayList I pass to `Collections.sort(list, myComparator)`. What I don't understand is how is the list I am passing containing null values?

Comment: Instead of down voting, tell me what's I'm doing wrong. I've spent hours scouring the web and SO trying to answer this myself. Give me a break.

Comment: You should really check what values you actually getting for this: `StringUtils.substringBetween(title, "mindhive podcast/", ".mp3")`

Comment: @JaidynBelbin - You are probably getting down votes because this seems like a post that can be fixed if you debug your code (and APis)

Comment: @JaidynBelbin scouring the web is nice, but a few minutes of debugging would have quickly pointed you to the source of the problem.

Comment: I am definitely sure all the Strings I am using that on are being added to the list properly. I can see the correct output when the Strings are added to my ListView.

Comment: @JaidynBelbin no you don't. See the answer below.

Comment: What String did you pass for o1 and o2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StringUtils.substringBetween()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) specifies several cases in which it will return null. Presumably that's causing null values to be added to your `formattedTitles` list, which in turn cause an NPE in your `extractInt()` method.