# Sorting Strings that contains number in kotlin

Tags: android, collections, kotlin, mutablelist

I wanna sort some strings that contain numbers but after a sort, it becomes like this `["s1", "s10", "s11", ... ,"s2", "s21", "s22"]`. after i search i fount this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java) with same problem. but in my example, I have `mutableList<myModel>`, and I must put all string in `myModel.title` for example into a mutable list and place into under code:

```
   val sortData = reversedData.sortedBy {
          //pattern.matcher(it.title).matches()
             Collections.sort(it.title, object : Comparator<String> {
                override fun compare(o1: String, o2: String): Int {
                    return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2)
                }

                 fun extractInt(s: String): Int {
                     val num = s.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
                     // return 0 if no digits found
                     return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
                 }
            })
        }
```

I have an error in `.sortedBy` and `Collections.sort(it.title)`, may please help me to fix this.

Comment: "I have an error": would you reveal which one?

Comment: at first, I must find a way to convert it.title to mutable list. because Collections.sort need that. I don't know how to push all it.title from a model into a mutable list and then I think I must use return before Collections.sort for fixing .sortedBy

Comment: don't mix `Collections.sort` and `sortedBy`. You may want to have a look at `sortWith` instead.... also: `sortedBy` and `sortedWith` are similar (they return a new list), whereas `sortWith` operates on the current list...

Comment: how can the accepted answer be **the** answer to your problem? it is way too complicated than any other answer, it uses `Observable`/`Subscriber`, something you didn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution can be this:

```
  reversedData.toObservable()
                    .sorted { o1, o2 ->
                        val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                        val matcher = pattern.matcher(o1.title)
                        val matcher2 = pattern.matcher(o2.title)

                        if (matcher.find()) {
                            matcher2.find()
                            val o1Num = matcher.group(0).toInt()
                            val o2Num = matcher2.group(0).toInt()

                            return@sorted o1Num - o2Num
                        } else {
                            return@sorted o1.title?.compareTo(o2.title ?: "") ?: 0
                        }
                    }
                    .toList()
                    .subscribeBy(
                        onError = {
                            it
                        },
                        onSuccess = {
                            reversedData = it
                        }
                    )
```

Comment: Use Kotlin's regex extensions, they're shorter and simpler. Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `sortWith` instead of sortBy
for example:

```
class Test(val title:String) {
  override fun toString(): String {
    return "$title"
  }
}

val list = listOf<Test>(Test("s1"), Test("s101"),
Test("s131"), Test("s321"), Test("s23"), Test("s21"), Test("s22"))
val sortData = list.sortedWith( object : Comparator<Test> {
override fun compare(o1: Test, o2: Test): Int {
    return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2)
}

fun extractInt(s: Test): Int {
    val num = s.title.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
    // return 0 if no digits found
    return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
}
```

})

will give output:

`[s1, s21, s22, s23, s101, s131, s321]`

Comment: how I must push all it.title into a list and use in sortData ?

Comment: @MehrdadDolatkhah I update my sample, hopefully it can give you the idea how to solve your problem, how to access title (attribute). change class `Test` with your `MyModel` class

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution based on the data you posted:

```
sortedBy { "s(\\d+)".toRegex().matchEntire(it)?.groups?.get(1)?.value?.toInt() }
```

Of course I would move the regex out of the lambda, but it is a more concise answer this way.

Answer (score 2):

As you state that you need a [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html), but don't have one yet, you should use [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) or [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) (in case you want to work with a comparator) instead and you get just a (new) list out of your current one, e.g.:

```
val yourMutableSortedList = reversedData.sortedBy {
  pattern.find(it)?.value?.toInt() ?: 0
}.toMutableList() // now calling toMutableList only because you said you require one... so why don't just sorting it into a new list and returning a mutable list afterwards?
```

You may want to take advantage of [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) (or Javas `Comparator.comparing`) for `sortedWith`.

If you just want to sort an existing mutable list use [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html) (or `Collections.sort`):

```
reversedData.sortWith(compareBy {
  pattern.find(it)?.value?.toInt() ?: 0
})

// or using Java imports:
Collections.sort(reversedData, Compatarator.comparingInt {
  pattern.find(it)?.value?.toInt() ?: 0 // what would be the default for non-matching ones?
})
```

Of course you can also play around with other comparator helpers (e.g. mixing nulls last, or similar), e.g.:

```
reversedData.sortWith(nullsLast(compareBy {
  pattern.find(it)?.value
}))
```

For the samples above I used the following [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html#kotlin.text.Regex):

```
val pattern = """\d+""".toRegex()
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers on this page worked for me, or were too confusing, so I'm sharing my simpler solution that I came up with:

#### Short answer:

Simply call:

```kotlin
yourArray.sortedWith(::numberAwareAlphabeticalSort)
```

And what is `numberAwareAlphabeticalSort`, you ask? It's a simple function that you copy-paste somewhere into your code. See full answer below:

#### Long answer:

This example code below is fully copy-pasteable. Here's a link to a Kotlin REPL where you can try it out yourself: https://pl.kotl.in/oPGE-NekG

```kotlin
val unsortedList = listOf(
    "Zebra",
    "Title 1",
    "Title 10",
    "A title 2",
    "Title 3",
    "Aardvark",
)

// Our helper function which looks for numbers at the end of a string:
fun extractIntegerFromEndOfString(input: String): Int? {
    val words = input.split(" ")
    val lastWord = words.lastOrNull()

    return if (lastWord != null && lastWord.all { it.isDigit() }) {
        lastWord.toInt()
    } else {
        null
    }
}

// Our actual sorting function:
fun numberAwareAlphabeticalSort(item1: String, item2: String): Int {
    val number1 = extractIntegerFromEndOfString(item1)
    val number2 = extractIntegerFromEndOfString(item2)

    return if (number1 != null && number2 != null) {
        // Slice off the number from the end of both strings:
        //   - if the remaining portions of each string are identical, then compare the two integer values that
        //     you extracted
        //   - otherwise, simply compare the two remaining portions alphabetically
        val remaining1 = item1.substring(0, item1.length - number1.toString().length).trim()
        val remaining2 = item2.substring(0, item2.length - number2.toString().length).trim()

        if (remaining1 == remaining2) {
            number1.compareTo(number2)
        } else {
            remaining1.compareTo(remaining2)
        }
    } else {
        // Otherwise, one or both items don't have numbers at the end, so just compare them alphabetically:
        item1.compareTo(item2)
    }
}

val sortedIntelligently = unsortedList.sortedWith(::numberAwareAlphabeticalSort)

sortedIntelligently.map { println(it) }
// Outputs:
//
// A title 2
// Aardvark
// Title 1
// Title 3
// Title 10
// Zebra
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a custom comparator for my JSON sorting. It can be adapted from bare String/Number/Null

```
fun getComparator(sortBy: String, desc: Boolean = false): Comparator<SearchResource.SearchResult> {
    return Comparator { o1, o2 ->
        val v1 = getCompValue(o1, sortBy)
        val v2 = getCompValue(o2, sortBy)

        (if (v1 is Float && v2 is Float) {
            v1 - v2
        } else if (v1 is String && v2 is String) {
            v1.compareTo(v2).toFloat()
        } else {
            getCompDefault(v1) - getCompDefault(v2)
        }).sign.toInt() * (if (desc) -1 else 1)
    }
}

private fun getCompValue(o: SearchResource.SearchResult, sortBy: String): Any? {
    val sorter = gson.fromJson<JsonObject>(gson.toJson(o))[sortBy]
    try {
        return sorter.asFloat
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        try {
            return sorter.asString
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            return null
        }
    }
}

private fun getCompDefault(v: Any?): Float {
    return if (v is Float) v else if (v is String) Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY else Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
}
```

Comment: So adapt your comparator and share adapted version please.