# How to sort items in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I wanted to sort the items in recyclerView. I have usernames such as 20ABC1, 20ABC2,..., 20ABC10,..etc.

I have tried answers from the related questions one of which was:

```
public static final Comparator<Users> BY_NAME_ALPHABETICAL = (users, t1) -> users.Username.compareTo(t1.Username);
```

But this does not solve the problem exactly. 20ABC10, 20ABC11,...20ABC19 comes above 20ABC2. I think it is because it checks character by character.

Any way I can solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural sort order string comparison in Java - is one built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in)

Comment: you need to search natural sort there is implementation for comparator available. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in

Comment: Although @KaranMer you are correct. But my type of issue can be solved by this answer by Bohemian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java

Answer (score 1):

My Issue got solved by using this answer [Sorting Strings that contains number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java) by Bohemian where he removed the alphabets from the strings and compared the remaining `ints`

```
Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
    }

    int extractInt(String s) {
        String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
        // return 0 if no digits found
        return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Observable<User> getUsersWithBlogs() {
return Observable.fromIterable(UserCache.getAllUsers())
.filter(user -> user.blog != null && !user.blog.isEmpty())
.sorted((user1, user2) -> user1.name.compareTo(user2.name));
}
```

Comment: We don't know if he is using RxJava

Answer (score 0):

put this in your adapter

```
void sortByName(boolean isDescending) {
    if (mDataList.size() > 0) {
        Collections.sort(mDataList, new Comparator<Users>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Users object1, Users object2) {
                if (isDescending)
                    return object2.getUsername().toLowerCase().compareTo(object1.getUsername().toLowerCase().trim());
                else
                    return object1.getUsername().toLowerCase().compareTo(object2.getUsername().toLowerCase().trim());
            }
        });
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
adapter.sortByName( true||false );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try and get back asap.

Comment: Same problem man. Result is 20ABC1, 20ABC10, 20ABC2, 20ABC3, 20ABC4, 20ABC5

Comment: @AshishYadav give this a try `Collections.sort(mDataList);`

Comment: downvoted since you're not explaining what your code does

Answer (score 0):

Using kotlin,

```
val comp: Comparator<Users> = Comparator { o1, o2 -> o1.Username.trim().compareTo(o2.Username.trim()) }
Collections.sort(users, comp)
```

Do the same for java.

Comment: It should solve the problem. I think you are doing something wrong. try tolowercase()

Comment: So by your solution what should come up 20ABC10 or 20ABC2? For me 20ABC10 is showing up and thats the problem. Otherwise normally the sorting is happening just fine.