# How to sort strings based on the integer value present inside it in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

suppose I have different sets of strings like:

**String 1 :-**
Indian Chess League 2021
Online (Play From Home)
E Sports
price 99 onwards

**String 2 :-**
Weekly Chess Maha Muqabla
Online (Play From Home)
E Sports
price 225 onwards

**String 3 :-**
Call of Duty Mobile Tournament
Online (Play From Home)
E Sports
price 300 onwards

**String 4 :-**
Green 10KM Challenge – Get India`s Biggest Medal
Your Place and Your Time: India
E Sports
price 399

**String 5 :-**
Free Fire Solo And Squad (Bermuda)
Online (Play From Home)
E Sports
price 100 onwards

***String 6 :-**
Johnson Call Of Duty Mobile Tournament
Online (Play From Home)
E Sports
price 100 onwards

**String 8 :-**
Online Martial Arts Coaching for Kids at Home
Online Streaming
Mixed Martial Arts
price 1180 onwards

**String 9:-**
Call of Duty Battle Royale In Aid Of Sightsavers
Online (Play From Home): India
E Sports
price 100

Here, I have **print the strings in the ascending order based on the *price***, so how can I do it.

Thanks in advance. :)
Preferred language is JAVA

Comment: If the preferred language is java then why did you put the `python` tag?

Comment: First define the [_natural ordering_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for such prices and then implement `Comparable` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in Java:

```
    strings.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> {
                int priceIndex = s.indexOf("price") + "price ".length();
                int spaceAfterPrice = s.indexOf(" ", priceIndex);
                int endPriceIndex = spaceAfterPrice != -1 ? spaceAfterPrice:s.length();
                return Double.parseDouble(s.substring(priceIndex, endPriceIndex));
            }))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Indian Chess League 2021 Online (Play From Home) E Sports price 99 onwards
Free Fire Solo And Squad (Bermuda) Online (Play From Home) E Sports price 100 onwards
Johnson Call Of Duty Mobile Tournament Online (Play From Home) E Sports price 100 onwards
Call of Duty Battle Royale In Aid Of Sightsavers Online(Play From Home):India E Sports price 100
Weekly Chess Maha Muqabla Online (Play From Home) E Sports price 225 onwards
Call of Duty Mobile Tournament Online (Play From Home) E Sports price 300 onwards
Green 10KM Challenge – Get India`s Biggest Medal Your Place and Your Time: India E Sports price 399
Online Martial Arts Coaching for Kids at Home Online Streaming Mixed Martial Arts price 1180 onwards
```

Comment: Note now this approach relies on the _natural ordering_ of [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a comparator and remove all of the non-number characters then compare those numbers and order them accordingly. maybe this can point you in the correct direction: [Sorting Strings that contains number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java)